# Physics World error

Tags: eclipse, box2d, andengine, game-physics

Really simple I am using And engine and the box2d extension and my project is stuck because when I try to use Physics World it says it cannot be resolved to a type. I've also tried using shift + control + o but that doesn't import anything any help at all would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Check in your properties of particular project, whether you had set the box2d extension as lib or not.
And also clean your project and run it.